# Making an incremental counter for scores

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How can I make a counter that will increment (run through) from zero to the score attained within two seconds? I plan to use this for displaying the final score in game over popup. I am not really too sure how to go about this. Please help.

Comment: I'm guessing you are asking for visually showing the counter going to the high score from zero?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code you can use to setup your animation (using scheduler) according to given values:

```
float secs = 2.0f;
float deciSecond = 1 / 10;
newScore = 100;

currentScore = 0;
scoreInDeciSecond = (newScore / secs) * deciSecond;
[self schedule:@selector(counterAnimation) interval:deciSecond];
```

And this is how your method will handle the animation:

```
- (void)counterAnimation {
   currentScore += scoreInDeciSecond;
   if (currentScore >= newScore) {
      currentScore = newScore;
      [self unschedule:@selector(counterAnimation)];
   }
   scoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentScore];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't know cocos2d and how it displays text or uses timers, but here is how to do it with pure iOS SDK. If you know cocos2d, it shouldn't be a problem converting it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    highScoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 75.0)];
    [self displayHighScore];
}

-(void)displayHighScore {
    highScore = 140;
    currentValue = 0;

    NSString* currentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentValue];
    [highScoreLabel setText:currentString];
    [self.view addSubview:highScoreLabel];

    int desiredSeconds = 2; //you said you want to accomplish this in 2 seconds
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: (desiredSeconds/highScore) // this allow the updating within the 2 second range
                                     target: self
                                   selector: @selector(updateScore:)
                                   userInfo: nil
                                    repeats: YES];
}

-(void)updateScore:(NSTimer*)timer {
    currentValue++;

    NSString* currentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentValue];
    [highScoreLabel setText:currentString];

    if (currentValue == highScore) {
        [timer invalidate]; //stop the timer because it hit the same value as high score
    }
}
```